# Need help with Image processing using Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am a new programmer in Python and I am trying to do some image processing. I want to incorporate a selection feature on an image with the help of the mouse. The image will display and then the user will select a part of the image with the mouse which will get saved as a new image. I have idea about opening, displaying and saving an image but I have no idea if we can select an image in Python using any algorithm. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: I think I can do this using pygame. I got told about it in another forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout PIL (Python Imaging Library):

http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: The library has allowed me to do everything except selection using mouse, but I will check it again nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what image library you are using. But to create a subset of an image using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) look [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm) under the chapter "Cutting, Pasting and Merging Images".

Comment: I already am reading and using information from that document, but the selection criteria using mouse doesnt fit in any of them. I know how to cut the image after the user selects it, but I dont know how he can select it in the 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do some complex shape selecting instead of rectangle cutting, you may look into OpenCV library,

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it and get back to you. I am looking for complex shape selection for selection of a zone in a world map jpg image I have.